# Generate war file from existing maven project

Tags: java, maven

I have downloaded a project from git. Its a web project using maven. I have eclipse in my machine and also maven is there. Now I want to create a war file from this project for deploying in Tomcat.

Any idea how I can do it. Command line will be a prefer option. I searched in Google but in most of the places it is asking to create a new Maven project or I am missing something.

Thank you

Comment: you can add packaging type as war to the pom file and run mvn install via cmd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `<packaging>war</packaging>` to your pom.xml, and run `mvn package` from the root of your project (i.e. where the pom.xml resides). If everything will be successful, you'll get a war file in the `target` directory. See: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates